# debugging cgo in visual studio code produces "multiple definition of" error

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, cgo

I am trying to debug a very simple `cgo` application in visual studio code and i am getting an error. When i `go run main.go` the application runs fine with no issues. But when i try to use the debugger in visual studio code, i get the following error:

```
# prolink007/simple-cgo
C:\Users\proli\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build964876546\b001\_x003.o: In function `Hello':
./hello.c:4: multiple definition of `Hello'
C:\Users\proli\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build964876546\b001\_x002.o:d:/projects/simple-cgo/main.go:6: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1
```

Here is my main.go

```
package main

/*
  #include "hello.c"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "errors"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    err := HelloWorld()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func HelloWorld() error {
    _, err := C.Hello()
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("error calling Hello function: " + err.Error())
    }

    return nil
}
```

Here is my hello.c

```
//hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

void Hello(){
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

Here is my launch.json.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i debug this application in visual studio code or is there a different means to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on [github](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2092#event-3478079754) and got an answer that solved my problem.

> I have reproducted it on linux.
>
> Can you try `go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" ./` with
>
> ```
> //#cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition 
> import "C"
> ```
>
> as described in [golang/go#16513](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16513#issuecomment-235787789) ?